# How to add my own files to django 'static' folder

Tags: python, django

I've read [django static files document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) and made my django static files settings like this

**setting.py**

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**html page**

```
<img src="{% static "admin/img/author.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

So if I address one of django default static files, it works fine. But if I add my own file and folders to the `static` folder, it doesn't show it.

I tried

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

But nothing changed. How can I make it work?

Comment: Did you have a ```{% load static %}``` at the top of your template? In addition check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#findstatic) out.

Comment: @theWanderer4865 I did that. But then I removed it and there were no difference. so I kept it that way

Comment: You should still have that in there, it might just silently be failing w/o it. Check the HTML that would be in your HTML page as well to see what `{% static "admin/img/author.jpg" %}` turned into. If its blank thats a problem

Comment: Also, use Django Debug Toolbar (along with the other development tools) to see where django expects to find files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things...

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'path/to/files/in/development',
)

STATIC_ROOT = 'path/where/static/files/are/collected/in/production'
```

When `DEBUG = True`, Django will automatically serve files located in any directories within `STATICFILES_DIRS` when you use the `{% static 'path/to/file' %}` template tag.

When `DEBUG = False`, Django will *not* serve any files automatically, and you are expected to serve those files using Apache, Nginx, etc, from the location specified in `STATIC_ROOT`.

When you run `$ manage.py collectstatic`, Django will copy any and all files located in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and also files within any directory named 'static' in 3rd party apps, into the location specified by `STATIC_ROOT`.

I typically structure my project root as such:

```
my_project/
    /static_assets/  (specified in STATICFILES_DIRS)
        /js
        /images

    /static (specified in STATIC_ROOT)
```

I hope that helps you understand how the staticfiles app works.

Comment: with this page help http://blog.xjtian.com/post/52685286308/serving-static-files-in-django-more-complicated I could finally figure it out. So you were right. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry. what do you mean by `you are expected to serve those files using Apache, Nginx, etc, from the location specified in STATIC_ROOT` ? Cause I can't make it work when `DEBUG=Flase`

Comment: I think you need to take a close look at the documentation around how Django serves, or doesn't serve, static files. The staticfiles application **will not serve files** when `DEBUG = False`, and for good reason - Django is not meant to serve static files. You need to use Apache, Nginx or another Http server to serve static files from the location defined by `STATIC_ROOT` in a production environment.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really get it, by I'll search more as you suggested. Thank you.

Comment: The staticfiles app is only meant to be used during development as a convenience, so you don't have to set up an additional Http server. It is not intended for production use. It also provides a standardized way for 3rd party apps to integrate static media into your project by way of the `collectstatic` command and the related settings.

Comment: So if I want to upload my webpage to the server for people to see, I should use the real url for my CSS,JS,... like `src="/img/image.jpg"`?

Comment: The `{% static %}` template tag takes care of this URL for you based on your settings. You don't need to, nor should you, hard-code the path to these types of files.

Comment: But doesn't `DEBUG=False` makes `{% static %}` stops working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67999/discussion-between-brandon-and-alex-jolig).

Answer (score 1):

`STATIC_ROOT` is where files are collected and moved to when `collectstatic` runs.

If you want files to be consolidated to there they should be found by the [static file finder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders).

As an example, include the following in your settings

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ("django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
 "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder")
```

now for one of the apps that are a part of your project, create a folder called `static` and put something in it.

When you run  `collectstatic` you should see that file mentioned and it copied to your `STATIC_ROOT`

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)
```

to your `settings.py`.

Also, if you haven't already, make sure to include

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

in each of your templates where you wish to reference static files.

Lastly, make sure that the file you are referencing actually exists and the file path to it is correct.

Comment: `{% load static %}` should be `{% load static from staticfiles %}`

Comment: No it doesn't need to be

Comment: It does according to the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#template-tags

Comment: Ah yes in production if you're using STATICFILES_STORAGE. I was assuming the OP was in development. Good catch. I'll add the disclaimer to the edit.

Comment: Using `{% load static from static files %}` covers both use cases as `django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage` is the default.

Comment: Very true. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @Brandon when I use `{% load static from static files %}`  django throws this error. `'from' is not a valid tag library: Template library from not found, tried django.templatetags.from,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.from,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.from`

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Is `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `'django.core.context_processors.static',` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting?

Comment: @Brandon I'm using Django 1.7 and those parameters are included where you mentioned. But I'm still getting that error

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo in my comment. It should be `{% load static from staticfiles %}`

Comment: @Brandon Yes. thank you. there's no error now. But image still is not there. Does my project have to has an app? Cause I don't have one.

Comment: No, you just have to have the necessary settings, context processors, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Try to:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/img/author.jpg" alt="My image"/>
```

And in your view must be something like this:

```
...
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.conf import settings

def my_view(request):
    ...
    static_url = getattr(settings, 'STATIC_URL')
    ...
    return render_to_response(
        template_name,
        RequestContext(request, {
            'STATIC_URL': static_url,
        }))
```