# Some <script src> and <links src> are found by html others don't, even if they are in same file

Tags: html, django

I am trying to add some .js and some .css files to my html page, but some work others don't, even if they're in the same directory.

I tried moving the one that doesn't work to same directory of the ones that work, but when i open the html page in browser i get the error saying that it wasn't found(404). I tried using `manage.py collectstatic` command but also didn't work. I am running on debug mode.

```
<script src="{% static "admin-lte/dist/js/app.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'admin-lte/dist/js/moment.min.js' %}" ></script>
```

since they are in the same directory they were suppose to be found by the html i guess, but what i actually get is this error: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin-lte/dist/js/moment.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What is your application mode? Debug? If not DEBUG then you have to run `./manage.py collectstatic` to copy new static files into static root folder.

Comment: Debug.Yes. I tried that, ill update the question.

Comment: It should works. Did you try to clear cache on your browser. Maybe old script still work because caching or something. Btw, do you have these double quotes on your template? I mean the quotes after static keyword `<script src="{% static "admin-lte/dist/js/app.min.js" %}"></script>`

Comment: This quest helped me solve this problem:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640285/how-to-add-my-own-files-to-django-static-folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in settings.py.
Those lines:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static_assets',
)
```

and add the not working file(moment.min.js) to static_assets dir worked for me.

This awnser helped me understand how django work with static files:
[How to add my own files to django 'static' folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640285/how-to-add-my-own-files-to-django-static-folder). and solve my problem.